# Images rotated on chromecast

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I have a Chromecast sender application developed. I try to take a photo in portrait mode with my phone camera. When I try to send it to the Chromecast device, I see it rotated 90 degrees. 
This occurred on Samsung Note S3. On Nexus 5, it was showing in portrait mode. I have tried similar applications downloaded from the Google Play and the results were different. Some apps had the same issue while others could cast the photo in its correct orientation.

On another note, Is there a way to have a smooth transition between photos? currently I have the Default receiver app installed and the fade out is working fine. However, new images loads in chunks ... any suggestion on how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom receiver and use CSS to fade between images. Create a div with two image tags and set the CSS style for the div to:

```
-webkit-transition: opacity 3s linear;
```

Then use Javascript to toggle the opacity of the images:

```
image1.style.opacity=0;
image2.style.opacity=1;
```